# なのに vs. だけど in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I was corrected when I said the following.

> 勉強は**大変なのに**、諦めちゃだめ。

I was told that 大変だけど had to be used instead of 大変なのに.

Although in English, the word “although” works in a similar sentence, it doesn’t in Japanese.

Why is のに not appropriate in this case (*although studying is hard, you can’t give up*)?

Comment: You mean なので means *although*? If so, that is the source of confusion.

Comment: @sundowner right, I made the mistake in my question here, but the question remains, のにversus けど.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

（な）のに may also be used to show disappointment in addition to meaning "although". This is in contrast with （だ）けど, which is a neutral form of "but/although".

> 勉強は大変なのに、諦めちゃだめ。

Is incorrect because the clause 諦めちゃだめ is a command. Although （な）のに also expresses contrast, the clause that comes after it cannot express the speaker's opinion. This means that imperatives like the above cannot be used with （な）のに either.

More particularly, [this article](https://nihongokyoiku-shiken.com/keredomo-noni-temo-japanese/#i-4) mentions that the clause that comes after（な）のに cannot express a "command, request, intention, question, or judgement" of the speaker's.

Note: Although the previous argument was convincing, it was incorrect. Naruto's comment makes that pretty clear.

Comment: What about sentences like 彼女は貧乏なのに幸せそうだ or 勉強は大変なのに彼はよく頑張っている?

Comment: @naruto that’s a good point. I guess it also shows contrast. Let me fix that